# How to write my own interpolation method

Tags: interpolation, algorithm, implementation-details, splines

I was comparing results of spline interpolation in *[Mathematica](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html)* and [C++/gsl-library](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Interpolation-Types.html#index-gsl_005finterp_005fcspline)

Results of interpolation are different if I use `Method -> "Spline", InterpolationOrder -> 3` in *Mathematica* and [cubic spline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Interpolation-Example-programs.html) in C++.

I believe this is due to difference in methods used by *Mathematica* and C++.

While the method spline interpolation is generated in C++ is [known](ftp://www.lwr.kth.se/CoupModel/GSL/interpolation/cspline.c) I have no idea what *Mathematica* calls a cubic spline (probably [`BSpline`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/BSplineCurve.html) , but I am not sure as C++ doesn't seem to have implementation of `BSpline`, so I can't compare)

I thought of implementing [C++ spline](ftp://www.lwr.kth.se/CoupModel/GSL/interpolation/cspline.c) method in *Mathematica* to make one to one comparison to C++. Other option would be to learn what algorithm does *Mathematica* use for spline interpolation, but I believe it is not open source, or is it?

Comment: No, it is most certainly not open-source. Ping support, however: they seem pretty responsive to such internals questions.

Comment: You can try plotting the function together with its first and second derivatives to figure out what's going on.  It should show clearly how the function is pieces together.

Comment: The method underlying the `"Spline"` option is more or less elaborated in the accepted answer to the duplicate question.